# javaFx and version netbeans and java 8

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, netbeans-8

i have netbeans 8 and openjdk8 installed in my machine. i am curently using ubuntu 18.04.
i need to install javaFx but i can't find the right version, everytime i try to create a javaFx fxml app i get this error :

```
> Failed to automatically set-up a JavaFX Platform.
> Please go to Platform Manager, create a non-default Java SE platform, then go to the JavaFX tab,
> enable JavaFX and fill in the paths to valid JavaFX SDK and JavaFX Runtime.
> Note: JavaFX SDK can be downloaded from JavaFX website.
```

also i tried installing different versions and add it in `tools->libraries..` but in vain.

Comment: Maybe this link could give you an answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091157/javafx-missing-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: please keep your tags focused (you explicitly ask about java/fx 8, so openjdk-11 is completely .. unrelated, to put it mildly ;) - or the other way round: if you are asking about version 11, change your question to clarify that fact. For now, I have removed the tag - feel free to edit along with the clarification :)

Comment: all that said and assuming you are looking for setup of javafx11 - follow the instructions at openjfx.io, they are guaranteed to work.